# Contact not visible in dialer

Tags: contacts

I cannot search my contact in key pad though I can see the contact in contacts app and also when I select a contact there is no more the option to send WhatsApp msg in my p10 lite already tried rebuild index data many times

Comment: Could you check in the Contacts app whether this contact still has a phone number associated with it?